# U1db-Qt not working as expected in ListView (Ubuntu Touch App Development)

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, qt

Recently, I've been trying to learn how to use the U1db Library (if that's what you call it), but it hasn't been working the way I expected it to work.

**Here is my code:**

```
 import QtQuick 2.4
 import Ubuntu.Components 1.3
 import U1db 1.0 as U1db

 MainView {
     objectName: "mainView"
     applicationName: "u1bdtest.evanlinjin"

     width: units.gu(100); height: units.gu(75);

     U1db.Database {
         id: aDatabase
         path: "aU1DbDatabase"
     }

     U1db.Document {
         id: aDocument
         database: aDatabase
         docId: 'helloWorld'
         contents: {"hello": {"world": [{"id": 3, "message": "Hello world."},
                                        {"id": 3.33, "message": "World, hello."},
                                        {"id": 3.66, "message": "HELLO WORLD!!!"}
                 ]}}
     }

     U1db.Index {
         id: documentIndex
         database: aDatabase
         expression: ["hello.world.id", "hello.world.message"]
     }

     U1db.Query {
         id: aQuery
         index: documentIndex
     }

     Page {
         title: i18n.tr("U1BdTest")

         Column {
             spacing: units.gu(1)
             anchors { margins: units.gu(2); fill: parent;}

             Label {id: label; objectName: "label"; text: i18n.tr("A U1Bd Test.");}

             ListView {
                 width: parent.width; height: parent.height; model: aQuery;
                 delegate: Text {x: 66; text: "(" + index + ", " + contents.id + ") " + contents.message}
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

**Here are the expected results in my "ListView":**

- (0, 3) Hello world.
- (1, 3.33) World, hello.
- (2, 3.66) HELLO WORLD!!!

However, only *"(0, 3) Hello world."* is displayed.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0DB0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it iterates over documents, not inside one document.

It took `hello.world[0].id` and `hello.world[0].message` from `aDocument`. If you add another document `aDocument2`, there will be two lines.

Maybe it should expand lists that it finds inside. But the description of the `Query` class probably says that one result corresponds to exactly one document:

> The Query class generates a filtered list of documents based on a query using the given Index.